# Mocha - Running test ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: node.js, gulp, mocha.js, babeljs

I am trying to run tests with `async/await` using `mocha`. The project architecture was setup before I started working on it and I have been trying to update it's node version to 8.9.4. The project is an isomorphic application and uses babel, gulp and webpack to run.
To run the tests we run a gulp task. There are two `.bablerc` files in the project. One in the root folder of the project and another in the test fodler.
Both have the same configuration:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {"exclude": ["transform-regenerator"]}],
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-root-import"
  ]
}
```

When I run the app locally there is no error returned anymore. However when I run the tests with `gulp test:api` I constantly get the error: `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

This is my gulp file in the test folder:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var gutil = require('gulp-util')
var gulpLoadPlugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')
var plugins = gulpLoadPlugins()
var babel = require('gulp-babel')


require('babel-register')({
    presets:["es2015", "react", "stage-1"]
});

// This is a cheap way of getting 'test:browser' to run fully before 'test:api' kicks in.
gulp.task('test', ['test:browser'], function(){
    return gulp.start('test:api')
});

gulp.task('test:api', function () {
    global.env = 'test'
    gulp.src(['test/unit-tests/server/**/*.spec.js'], {read: false})
        .pipe(plugins.mocha({reporter: 'spec'}))
        .once('error', function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            process.exit(1);
        })
        .once('end', function () {
            process.exit(0);
        })
});

gulp.task('default', ['test']);
```

Any help on why this is happening wouldd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Node version 8 already has support for `async/await` so you do not need Babel to transform it; indeed, your root .babelrc includes this preset to exclude the `regenerator` that would transform `async/await` (and introduce a dependency on regeneratorRuntime):

`["env", {"exclude": ["transform-regenerator"]}]`

However, in your test file, the configuration does not specify this preset. Instead, it specifies the preset `"es2015"`, which *does* include the unwanted `transform-regenerator` (as you can see at https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/). If you change this to match the presets in the root .babelrc, you'll get more consistent results.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely i ran into this issue after i upgraded to Node v8.10.0  from v8.6.x . I had used babel-require like so in my `test-setup.js`

`require('babel-register')();`

and the testing tools are Mocha,chai,enzyme + JSDOM . I was getting the same issue when i was making a async call to a API, also while using generator functions via sagas. Adding `babel-polyfill` seemed to have solved the issue.

`require('babel-register')();
 require('babel-polyfill');`

i guess even babel [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/#top) themselves advocate using polyfill for generators and such

> **Polyfill not included**
>   You must include a polyfill separately when using features that require it, like generators.

Comment: Same here, I was also doing an async call to an API and installed `babel-polyfill` and added it on the tests file (`import "@babel/polyfill"`) and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue when running mocha tests **from within Visual Studio Code**.

The **solution** was to add the necessary babel plugins in the Visual Studio Code `settings.json` :

```
"mocha.requires": [
    "babel-register",
    "babel-polyfill"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this error before myself when using **async/await**, **mocha**, **nyc**, and when attempting to run *coverage*. There's never an issue when leveraging mocha for running tests, just with *mocha* tests while leveraging **nyc** for running coverage.

```
  11) Filesystem:removeDirectory
       Filesystem.removeDirectory()
         Should delete the directory "./tmp".:
     ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
      at Context.<anonymous> (build/tests/filesystem.js:153:67)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

You can fix the issue a couple of different ways.

### Method 1 - NPM's `package.json`:

```
...
"nyc": {
    "require": [
      "@babel/register",
      "@babel/polyfill"
    ],
    ...
},
...
```

It really depends which **polyfill** package you're using. It's recommended to use the scoped (*@babel*) variant: `@babel/pollyfill`. However, if you're using `babel-polyfill` then ensure that's what you reference.

### Method 2 - Direct Import

`your-test-file.js` (es6/7):

```
...
import '@babel/polyfill';
...
```

OR

`your-test-file.js` (*CommonJS*):

```
...
require("@babel/polyfill");
...
```

Don't assign it to a variable, just import or require the package. Again, using the package name for the variant you've sourced. It includes the polyfill and resolves the error.

HTH